# How to create a dynamic page based on form data with a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, pages

I have a form that users fill out.  When they finish, they are redirected to a 3rd party site to set up payment options.  After completing the payment process, they are sent back to my site with a variety of $_POST variables.

My plugin needs to create a thank you page based on those POST variables.  It's a simple little page with a title and a few paragraphs of text.

*I do not want these pages to be stored in the database.*  They will be unique to each transaction.

I attached a function to `init` that parses the $_POST data (after sanitizing, of course.) That function creates two global variables: `$my_title` and `$my_content`  I'm not sure how to turn those into a page for the user, though.

The payment system will send users to `www.mysite.com/thank-you`

So far, I have a filter on `rewrite_rules_array` to add my url:

```
function my_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_rules) {
    $rule = array('thank-you/?$' => 'index.php?formresult=thank-you');
    $rewrite_rules = $rule + $rewrite_rules;
    return $rewrite_rules
}
```

I filter `query_vars` to add mine:

```
function my_insert_qv($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'formresult');
    return $vars;
}
```

Then, I have an action on `template_redirect` where I think the action should be.  Maybe this is the wrong path.

```
function my_template_redirect() {
    gloval $wp;
    $qvs = $wp->query_vars;
    if (array_key_exists( 'laundry', $qvs && $qvs['laundry'] == 'thank-you' ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set( 'is_404', false );
        // ... now what?
    }
}
```

How can I show the user a page that loads the default page template from the active theme and shows my dynamic title and content?

Comment: Would you be okay with one page in the WordPress db? If so you could set up a single "thank you" page which uses a custom page template. Put the code in that template to pull in the args from the querystring and display your custom content.

Comment: Yeah, that would work.  I'm trying to do it all without touching the theme... if that's what has to happen, so be it.  But, I'd like it to be one self-contained plugin.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. My brain skipped right over the "My plugin needs to..." bit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, though I'm not sure how meta, title, etc.. will behave, you'll want to test everything thoroughly!

```
function my_template_redirect() {
    global $wp;
    $qvs = $wp->query_vars;
    if (array_key_exists( 'laundry', $qvs && $qvs['laundry'] == 'thank-you' ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set( 'is_404', false );
        // ... now what?

        $post = new stdClass();
        $post->ID= -99; // fake ID, hehe
        $post->post_content = 'some content';
        $post->post_excerpt = 'an excerpt';
        $post->post_status ='publish';
        $post->post_title = 'My fake page';
        $post->post_type = 'page';
        $wp_query->queried_object = $post;
        $wp_query->post = $post;
        $wp_query->found_posts = 1;
        $wp_query->post_count = 1;
        $wp_query->max_num_pages = 1;
        $wp_query->is_page = 1;
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;
        $wp_query->posts = array($post);
        $wp_query->page = 1;
        $wp_query->is_post = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like what I need, but it's not quite working for me.  Looking at the debug info, I added lines for `$post->post_name` and `$wp_query->queried_object_id`.  Now the result is it shows the blog index and gives the notice `Trying to get property of non-object in .../wp-includes/post-template.php on line 485`  It looks to be trying to look up the page with id = -99, which fails. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried setting the fake page ID equal to 1.  That cleared up the notice, but still just showing the blog index.

Comment: @Peter G - sorry, don't know how to fix that, will have to do some tests myself later.

Comment: Thanks @Milo I've been trying to use it on all sorts of different hooks without luck.  It seems like such a simple idea, but apparently not.  I'd love an answer to this, but given time constraints I'll likely go the custom template route suggested above sometime tomorrow.

Comment: The template method worked out for me and got the job done.  I'm accepting this answer because it does show how to set up your own $post & $wp_query variables.