# add_rewrite_rule again

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

In general, the code [from this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3537/need-help-with-friendly-urls-in-wordpress) fit to me for 90%. One little change I need - I want all URL like *example.com/snpv/any_text/* direct not to index.php as in original code, but to **my.php** script in root of my **THEME** (not site!). So, I correct the code for my needs:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'make_flush_rules');
function make_flush_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('snpv/([^/]+)', '/wp-content/themes/lightsaber/my.php?prm1=$matches[1]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules(false);
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'make_query_vars');
function make_query_vars($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = 'prm1';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

To make picture clear:

- lightsaber-my Theme
- my.php-just independent script. It is not page (or, to be precise, not WP page) or page template, just php-code to generate some output

I create this plugin and activate it. Enter URL example.com/snpv/ABC/ and get 404 page. :(
How to correct problem? Thanks!

Comment: you can't direct rewrite rules to other scripts, everything should still be directed to index.php, but you should also set up a hook early in the request to check if your special query var has been set and execute your code then.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! I understand - straight redirect to my.php is impossible. :( Can you tell, please, the name of hook (filter?) you mention above?

Comment: see answer with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example with `template_redirect` that loads your php script if the `prm1` query var is set:

```
// set up the rewrite
add_action( 'init', 'wpse36736_setup_rewrites' );
function wpse36736_setup_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule( 'snpv/([^/]+)', 'index.php?prm1=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

// add query var
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpse36736_query_vars');
function wpse36736_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'prm1';
    return $query_vars;
}

// check the query var on template_redirect
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'wpse36736_template_redirect' );
function wpse36736_template_redirect(){
    global $wp_query;
    if( $wp_query->get( 'prm1' ) ):
        include( get_template_directory() . "/prm1.php" );
        exit();
    endif;
}
```

You can then access `prm1` in your script via:

```
$prm1 = get_query_var( 'prm1' );
```

The only strange thing about this is the way WordPress interprets this query, the behavior in 3.3 seems to be a bit different than with previous versions. If you inspect the global `$wp_query` variable set for any of these requests, everything is populated as if it's the main posts page and `is_404` is false. I recall this wasn't the case back when I tried to help out on [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28408/how-to-create-a-dynamic-page-based-on-form-data-with-a-plugin).

Anyway, what I typically do in this situation is create a page, say `snpv`, and change the rewrite rule to `'index.php?pagename=snpv&prm1=$matches[1]'`.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `index.php`, register a query var, add a condition and finally call the exit function? The author of the question is trying to use an independent php script directly. How can we get that working?