# how to rewrite folder name in url to another name

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I am wondering wether it's possible to use Apaches `.htaccess` to rewrite a folder name - using a WordPress function.

Lets say I have a url like:

```
http://example.com/folder1/folder2/page.php
```

Now I want to rewrite the url to (for example)

```
http://example.com/testing/folder2/page.php
```

The `folder1` is an existing url. How can I change it to `testing`?

The following I found "somewhere in the internet":

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 301 /testing/folder2/(.*) /folder1/folder2/$1
</IfModule>
```

I need it as a PHP function to use it in WordPress.

Comment: Please read [ask], take a look at the editor and use the editor buttons when asking questions. Keep that in mind for further questions. Thanks.

Comment: Is this about rewriting or redirecting?

Comment: rewriting @ialocin

Comment: Ok, the code you posted does perform a redirect.. What about [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/6891/22534) and/or [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/36736/22534).

Comment: I don't get what is the question about, is it htaccess question, or a php and how is it related to wordpress at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do rewrites in wordpress by using the `add_rewrite_rule()` function.

Please see:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, just what I needed after chaning the foldername (aka customer type name) I got too many 404. so I did:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 301 /old_custom_post_type/(.*) /new_custom_post_type/$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Don't use the answers to make comments.